# Unable to convert my string to hex message

Tags: go

Below has x which is my expected string
I am trying to recreate `y` myself to match my expected string. Basically trying to convert `"01"` to `"\x01"` so that I get the same byte when printed.

Now when I print `[]byte(x)` and `[]byte(y)` I want them to be the same but they aren't. Please help me recreate `x` with `"01"` as my input.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    //Expected string
    x := "\x01"
    //Trying to convert my 01 in string form to same as above - Basically recreate above string again
    y := "\\x" + "01"
    fmt.Println(x)
    fmt.Println(y)
    fmt.Println([]byte(x))
    fmt.Println([]byte(y))
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what i wanted - got my issue resolved ! :) Thanks all

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/hex"
)

func main() {
    //Expected string
    x := "\x01"
    //Trying to convert my 01 in string form to same as above - Basically recreate above string again
    y,err :=  hex.DecodeString("01")
    if err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(x)
    fmt.Println(y)
    fmt.Println([]byte(x))
    fmt.Println([]byte(y))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot build a string from a byte sequence that way... `\x01` is an escaping notation processed by the compiler when reading literal strings, you cannot use that processing at runtime.

To build a string with the bytes you want you can simply use

```
x := string([]byte{1, 2, 3, 4})
```